# Calling a mysql query inside another mysql query while loop

Tags: php, html, mysql

```
include "mysql.php";
          $query= "SELECT ID,name,displayname,established,summary,searchlink,imagename,image FROM institutions ORDER BY rand() ";
          $result=mysql_query($query,$db);
          while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result))
            {
              echo "<div class='grid-item item1' style='background: ".ran_col().";'>"; 

                $query1= "SELECT content FROM ".$row['name']." limit 1";
                $result1=mysql_query($query1,$db);
                while($row1=mysql_fetch_array($result1))
                {
                            echo "<div class='content-short' data-id=".$row['name'].">";
                                $string = $row1['content'];
                                if (strlen($string) > 200) 
                                {
                                $trimstring = substr($string, 0,200). '...';
                                } 
                                else 
                                {
                                $trimstring = substr($string,0). '...';
                                }
                                echo $trimstring;

                            echo "</div>";
                }
              echo <"/div">;
            }
```

What code should do:

The code should grab data from institution table and after that `$row['name']` should be used as table for next mysql query where from that `$row['name']` table `$row['content']` should be grabbed

but it is not working as expeted

Comment: **STOP** using the deprecated `mysql_*`API

Comment: i am just trying and definately will change this @Jens

Comment: a very bad idea of using query inside a loop. instead you should try some joins and get your job done instead of exhausting mysql server with continues requests for one one value

Answer (score 0):

You are using same variable everywhere. Change them to

```
include "mysql.php";
          $query= "SELECT ID,name,displayname,established,summary,searchlink,imagename,image FROM institutions ORDER BY rand() ";
          $result=mysql_query($query,$db);
          while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result))
            {
              echo "<div class='grid-item item1' style='background: ".ran_col().";'>"; 

                $query1= "SELECT content FROM ".$row['name']." limit 1";
                $result1=mysql_query($query1,$db);
                while($row1=mysql_fetch_array($result1))
                {
                            echo "<div class='content-short' data-id=".$row['name'].">";
                                $string = $row1['content'];
                                if (strlen($string) > 200) 
                                {
                                $trimstring = substr($string, 0,200). '...';
                                } 
                                else 
                                {
                                $trimstring = substr($string,0). '...';
                                }
                                echo $trimstring;

                            echo "</div>";
                }
              echo <"/div">;
            }
```

**EDIT:**

Also your query is wrong

```
$query1= "SELECT content FROM ".$row['name']" limit 1";
```

to

```
$query1= "SELECT content FROM ".$row['name']." limit 1";
```

Comment: Warning: mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource the warning is for line  while($row1=mysql_fetch_array($result1)) @harshit